# how to center text vertically in a table

Tags: tables

This is my code. I want to make the Grid and Linear text not to touch the top line. I am not able to do that.

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont
\caption{table}
\label{tab:table1}
\resizebox{17cm}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|*{17}{c|}}
\cline{1-17}
%\cline{1-1} \cline{9-10}
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{|c|} {Grid}   & \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Linear} \\[2ex]
\hline
 N & Pmd & Pfa & N.Pmd & N.Pfa & 2N.Pmd & 2N.Pfa &  N\textsubscript{gd}(N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pmd) & N\textsubscript{gd}(N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pfa) & h\textsubscript{gd1} & h\textsubscript{gd2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_gd} & N\textsubscript{ln}(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pmd) & N\textsubscript{ln}(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pfa) & h\textsubscript{ln1} & h\textsubscript{ln2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_lm} \\ [1ex] 
\hline
10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.5   & 1 & 1   & 2  & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\[1ex]
\hline
50 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 2.5   & 5 & 5   & 10 & 13 & 13 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 11 & 11 & 5 & 5 & 5\\[1ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either increase the row height with `\arraystretch` (this will change globally) command or with a vertical rule with required height, but with `0pt` width.  Here, I defined a `\Strut` command for this purpose and used in the `\multicolumn`.

[image]

```
\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont
\caption{table}
\label{tab:table1}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\newcommand\Strut[1]{\vrule height #1 width 0pt depth 0pt}
\resizebox{14cm}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|*{17}{c|}}
\cline{1-17}
%\cline{1-1} \cline{9-10}
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{|c|} {Grid \Strut{2pc}}  &     \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Linear} 
\\[2ex]
\hline
 N & Pmd & Pfa & N.Pmd & N.Pfa & 2N.Pmd & 2N.Pfa &  N\textsubscript{gd}    (N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pmd) & N\textsubscript{gd}    (N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pfa) & h\textsubscript{gd1} & h\textsubscript{gd2} &     h\textsubscript{opt\_gd} & N\textsubscript{ln}(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pmd) &     N\textsubscript{ln}(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pfa) & h\textsubscript{ln1} &     h\textsubscript{ln2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_lm} \\ [1ex] 
\hline
10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.5   & 1 & 1   & 2  & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 &     1\\[1ex]
\hline
50 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 2.5   & 5 & 5   & 10 & 13 & 13 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 11 & 11 & 5 &     5 & 5\\[1ex]
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, do get rid of the statement `\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont`. Second, remove the spacing directives `[2ex]` and `[1ex]`. Third, add a directive such as `\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}` immediate after `\begin{table*}`. Separately, do also reduce the value of `\tabcolsep` (default value: `6pt`) to something like `2pt`, to keep the linear reduction in font size brought about by `\resizebox` from becoming too extreme (and risking rendering the entire table illegible). Finally, you should get rid of double-thickness vertical bars in the first header row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,array}
\usepackage[textwidth=17cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[t]
%\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont
\caption{table}
\label{tab:table1}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|*{17}{c|}}
\hline
%\cline{1-1} \cline{9-10}
\multicolumn{7}{|c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Grid}   & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Linear} \\
\hline
 N & Pmd & Pfa & N.Pmd & N.Pfa & 2N.Pmd & 2N.Pfa &  N\textsubscript{gd}(N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pmd) & N\textsubscript{gd}(N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pfa) & h\textsubscript{gd1} & h\textsubscript{gd2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_gd} & N\textsubscript{ln}(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pmd) & N\textsubscript{ln}(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pfa) & h\textsubscript{ln1} & h\textsubscript{ln2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_lm} \\  
\hline
10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.5   & 1 & 1   & 2  & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\hline
50 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 2.5   & 5 & 5   & 10 & 13 & 13 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 11 & 11 & 5 & 5 & 5\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: Upon studying your table a bit more, it occurred to me that with a mild re-organization of the header row, it's no longer necessary to resize the tabular material drastically in order to make it fit inside the text block. A simple 10% linear reduction in size, brought about via a `\small` directive, suffices. I also recommend getting rid of all vertical rules and replacing `\hline` with the more sophisticated macros of the `booktabs` package: `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule`. I would also suggest you replace `.` in the various header entries with `\cdot`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,array,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[textwidth=17cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\small % 10% linear reduction of font size
\caption{table}
\label{tab:table1}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % let LaTeX figure out the intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{c @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{16}{c} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Grid} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Linear} \\
\cmidrule{8-12} \cmidrule{13-17}
N & Pmd & Pfa & N$\cdot$Pmd & N$\cdot$Pfa & 2N$\cdot$Pmd & 2N$\cdot$Pfa &  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{N\textsubscript{gd} >} &  
h\textsubscript{gd1} & h\textsubscript{gd2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_gd} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{N\textsubscript{ln} >} & 
h\textsubscript{ln1} & h\textsubscript{ln2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_lm} \\  
\cmidrule{8-9} \cmidrule{13-14}
\multicolumn{7}{c}{} & 2N$\cdot$Pmd & 2N$\cdot$Pfa & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{} & 2N$\cdot$Pmd & 2N$\cdot$Pfa \\
\midrule
10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 0.5   & 1 & 1   & 2  & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
50 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 2.5   & 5 & 5   & 10 & 13 & 13 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 11 & 11 & 5 & 5 & 5\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I propose two solutions, with a larger font size, that doesn't require `resizebox`:

one with vertical lines.The content of rows is vertically centred with the `cellspace` package, that ensures a minimal vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells in columns prefixed with the letter `S`.

A more professional looking table, with only horizontal rules, in which the padding is realised with the `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep` lengths of the `booktabs` package.

Both solutions use `makecell`, which allows for linebreaks in cells.

Finally, I took the liberty to consider that columns6 to 7, corresponding to trivial calculations, were unnecessary, as the formulae are mentioned in columns 8-9 and 13-14 – but maybe I'm wrong. There results a table with 13 columns which fits between the margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx,array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage[textwidth=17cm, showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\null\vskip1cm
\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{3.6pt}
  \caption{table1}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{13}{Sc|}}
    \cline{4-13}
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{5}{Sc|} {Grid} & \multicolumn{5}{Sc|}{Linear} \\
    \hline
    N & Pmd & Pfa & \makecell{N\textsubscript{gd} \\(N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pmd)} & \makecell{N\textsubscript{gd}\\(N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pfa)} & h\textsubscript{gd1} & h\textsubscript{gd2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_gd} & \makecell{N\textsubscript{ln}\\(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pmd)} & \makecell{N\textsubscript{ln}\\(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pfa)} & h\textsubscript{ln1} & h\textsubscript{ln2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_lm} \\
    \hline
    10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \hline
    50 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 13 & 13 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 11 & 11 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
  \centering\footnotesize\setlength\tabcolsep{3.6pt}
  \renewcommand\cellalign{bc}
  \caption{table1}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{*{13}{c}}
    \noalign{\vspace*{-\aboverulesep}}\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{4-13}
    \multicolumn{3}{c}{} & \multicolumn{5}{c} {Grid} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Linear} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){4-8}\cmidrule(lr){9-13}
    N & Pmd & Pfa & \makecell{N\textsubscript{gd} \\(N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pmd)} & \makecell{N\textsubscript{gd}\\(N\textsubscript{gd}>2N.Pfa)} & h\textsubscript{gd1} & h\textsubscript{gd2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_gd} & \makecell{N\textsubscript{ln}\\(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pmd)} & \makecell{N\textsubscript{ln}\\(N\textsubscript{ln}>2N.Pfa)} & h\textsubscript{ln1} & h\textsubscript{ln2} & h\textsubscript{opt\_lm} \\
    \midrule
    10 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 5 & 5 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 3 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
    \addlinespace
    50 & 0.05 & 0.10 & 13 & 13 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 11 & 11 & 5 & 5 & 5 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Zarko: My editor struck again! I don't understand why from time to time it inserts a series of `&` ($9$ in all here, inside the `\makecell` commands) I've corrected it, you should be able to compile now. Thanks for pointing the problem.

Comment: @Zarko: I removed the code and copied the exact code I've just compiled. Does it compile for you now?

Comment: Now all works! You make very interesting and good solution! I will erase my comments soon ...